# Knockout js to mysql database for dynamic values not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, knockout.js

I'm not being able to send the value of the `brandName` to the database. I'm trying to send data to with `ajax`. I also have a `addBrandName` button that adds new field when clicked, that means I want to `insert` multiple input values to the database at once. But so far, I'm having problem with it. Any suggestion where the problem is  or how can I correct it? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/6s6z9bm9/) for the demonstration.

My `html` section is:

```
<button data-bind='click: addBrandName'>Add a brand</button>
<table data-bind="foreach: brandNames">
   <tbody>
      <td>
         <label>Brand name</label>
         <input type="text" data-bind='value: brandName'>
      </td>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addToDB">Add to database</button>
```

And the script:

```
var brandNamesModel = function(brandNames) {
    var self = this;
    self.brandNames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(brandNames));

    self.addBrandName = function() {
        self.brandNames.push({
            brandName: ""
        });
    };
};

this.addToDB = function() {
    var toDB = {
        'bName': this.brandName()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'detail': toDB,
            'action': 'insert'
        },
        success: function() {
            self.brandName("");
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new brandNamesModel());
```

The action.php is:

```
<?php
$db = new MySqli('localhost', 'ashonko', '', 'tutorials');

$action = (!empty($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
$detail = (!empty($_POST['detail'])) ? $_POST['detail'] : '';

if (!empty($detail)) {
    $bName = $detail['bName'];
}

switch ($action) {
    case 'insert':
        $db->query("INSERT INTO products SET name = '$bName'");
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no `brandName` property in `brandNamesModel`. So when you access `this.brandName()` it's throwing an error. Do you want to save a single `brandName` or a collection of `brandName`s?

Comment: what you see when executing console.log(toDB)?

Comment: console says, `TypeError: this.brandNames is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `brandName` property in `brandNamesModel`. So when you access `this.brandName()` here:

```
var toDB = {
    'bName': this.brandName()
};
```

it's throwing an error. `brandName` is a property of each item of your collection `brandNames`.So, if you want to save the most recent item added to your collection, you can change it to:

```
this.addToDB = function() {
    if(this.brandName().length == 0)
        return;

    // gets the last brandName entered
    var toDB = {
        'bName': this.brandNames()[this.brandNames().length -1].brandName
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'detail': toDB,
            'action': 'insert'
        },
        success: function() {
            // this will also throw an error
            self.brandName("");
        }
    });
};
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6s6z9bm9/3/) for testing the above code.

But you need to change the logic of inputs. You should have only one input rather than having an input in every `td`. Something like this:

```
<label>Brand name</label>

<!--This one is outside the foreach. Refers to the brandNamesModel-->
<input type="text" data-bind='value: brandName'>

<button data-bind='click: addBrandName'>Add a brand</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Brand Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: brandNames">
    <tr>
      <!--This brandname is referring to property in the array-->
      <td data-bind="text:brandName">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addToDB">Add to database</button>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6s6z9bm9/6/) demonstrating that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but even if I declare the property, it still is not inserting values to the database. And I'd like to insert all the value to the database table `products` in the column `name` with different `id`s for each item. Any possible solution?

Comment: @RajibBiswas If you add a property to the `brandNamesModel , you'd have to change the setup of how you're populating and displaying brandnames. Currently, for this example, you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6s6z9bm9/2/

Comment: with the example from Fiddle, when I click to add to database, it adds the word `Array` to the database table column. And whatever it is single or multiple values, every time it adds a single field and the word `Array` in it.

Comment: @RajibBiswas my bad. try it now https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6s6z9bm9/3/

Comment: Wow! Thanks, But I'm actually trying to Insert all the values. Not the last one only. Like if someone creates 2 fields for `Brand name` and input `Apple` and `Microsoft` as the values, I want to insert both `Apple` and `Microsoft` into 2 fields, not the `Microsoft` only. May be loop through all the inputs and add them all to database fields. Any suggestion?

Comment: @RajibBiswas this is a new question altogether and involves changing most of your logic.Since you're new to Knockout, I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6s6z9bm9/6/). I think this is what you're trying to do. For the saving part, I have just written comments what to do. It involves filtering KO array and you can find out by googling or KO documentation. You'll only learn when you try rather than me coding it for you. Besides, I don't know PHP :) You can search find out how to save collection on PHP. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much @adiga, Actually, it was part of my question from the beginning, may be I couldn't explain it earlier, my apologies. And I really appreciate your effort. :) :)